# how to delete class in parse local database

Tags: parse-platform

```
@IBAction func unPin(sender: AnyObject) {
guestInfo.unpinInBackground()
    guestInfo.deleteInBackground()

}
```

I add a button function to delete the guestInfo PFObject I've created.
I tried this function but it simply won't work.
I also tried delete with object names,also not working,
hoping somebody can solve this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what it does instead of working, precisely. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Do you know how to solve this Nathan Tuggy :)

Comment: Define 'simply won't work' - how are you testing and what result are you seeing...